# Service workers on cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, service-worker, sw-precache

Can i use service workers inside hybrids apps(ionic 1/cordova) running on android devices? I'm getting some errors when trying to install a service worker on ionic app running on android device, because android uses file protocol to serve files and service-workers require files to be served by HTTPS protocol or http(only for localhost):

> Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to
>   register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin
>   ('file://') is not supported.

It's not a traditional progressive web application running on mobile browser, but instead on android device (webview + cordova).

I need achieve that to leverage my app with cache strategies(using sw-precache e sw-toolbox from google) on my api calls.

Comment: It is not supported in android browser. You cannot check here http://caniuse.com/#search=service%20workers

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers), it is supported. The issue is with the protocol used.

If you read on [Service Workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers), you will see in prerequisites that in production you are required to use `HTTPS`.

Using Crosswalk might help though, take a look at [XWALK-5919](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-5919).