# Service Workers in Cordova Hybrid Mobile App

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, service-worker

we have done extensive work to determine if there is ANY possible way or hack that anyone has figured out to get service workers working in a Cordova app (not using Ionic)? Ionic actually doesn't work with true service workers either but that's another thread.

Obviously, the service worker has to come from a trusted host 'HTTPS' and our build comes from local host on File:///

We have tried the whitelist plugin, and we are aware there is an iOS plugin (which we don't want to fuss with) until we know we can also get them working on Android. Has anyone found a creative hack to make this work, or has Cordova updated to support this API yet (as it's the future of development)?

Even if you have constructed a hack solution we'd like to hear. Considered using PouchDB to help with offline access but that really doesn't help us run server tasks off the main thread and in the background, additionally we worry it could conflict with SQLite which we also use.

This seems like the last posts on this were quite some time ago so if any Cordova or PhoneGap folks could chime in and help a client-side rendered local host implement these, much appreciated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877656/how-to-use-service-workers-in-cordova-android-app